# Subtract percentage from input and put it in a paragraph

Tags: javascript

I want to make a PaySafeCard to PayPal exchange service with an fee of 10%. 
So, while ordering, I want the people to type in the funds of the PSC in an input, so a paragraph shows how much money they get on PayPal (-10%). The var ppfunds should be set in the paragraph with the ID "moneyuget" with a € sign after it. This is what I got so far and where I'm stuck.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pscfunds" onkeydown="feecalc()">
</div>
<p>PayPal funds you get with a fee:</p>
<p id="moneyuget">0,00€</p>
```

JS

```
var pscfunds = document.getElementById('pscfunds').value;
var number = parseFloat(pscfunds);
var ppfunds = number - (number * .10);
function feecalc() {
   ppfunds = document.getElementById('moneyuget').textContent;
}
```

Comment: You should use an event to update `#moneyuget` element, after that event. For example `onclick` or `onkeydown`.

Comment: `innerHTML` is for getting the markup inside of elements. You are using it improperly with the input element, that should be `.value`. Later, you then attempt to use `.value` to assign text to a paragraph element, that should be `.textContent`.

Comment: Updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var p = document.getElementById('moneyuget');

function feecalc() {
    var pscfunds = document.getElementById('pscfunds').value;
   var n = Number(pscfunds);
   p.textContent = (n - n*0.10).toFixed(2)+'€';
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pscfunds" onkeyup="feecalc()">
</div>
<p>PayPal funds you get with a fee:</p>
<p id="moneyuget">0.00€</p>
```